# I am getting error when trying to get substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the value which I am passing in QueryString in HTML page.
I wrote function for it, But it gives me below error:

> TypeError: str.substring is not a function

Below is my function:

```
function getQueryStringArray() {

        var str = window.location.search.substring(1).split('?');
        var res = str.substring(6,14);

        alert(str);
        alert(res);
    }
```

my URL is like:

```
http://localhost:50629/youtube/test.html?type=Mensworld
```

Comment: Why would there be more questionmarks in the `search` part of the URL? All you're getting in `location.search` is the string `type=Mensworld`

Answer (score 1):

`str` is an array since `.split('?');` creates an array of strings, and you cannot apply `.substring()` on an array. You need to apply it to its elements:

```
 for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
      var res = str[i].substring(6,14);
      alert(res);
 }
```

or

```
 var res = str[1].substring(6,14);
```

Comment: Sure dear, will do it,